# Conventional directory for application build source

Tags: directory-structure

I know this is rather subject to opinion but what are some good choices where on the file system to locate the source code of a build that the server builds (let's say it's a build/integration server)? E.g. there is `/usr/src` but I think that is rather a conventional location for shell-related stuff (correct me if wrong). How about `/usr/local/src`?

E.g. right now I check out *foo* (one of our apps we integrate) source code in `/var/lib/foo` but I think that may be a misleading reference. Of course it doesn't matter for execution purposes but I am trying to get in line with the convetions.

Comment: oh I think this is answered by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10816/23944. Admin should decide whether to delete this question unless it makes sense to keep it

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer there is slightly wrong (don’t use `/usr/local/src` for builds).

Answer (score 1):

[What is the "/usr/local/src" folder meant for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10814/86440) addresses `/usr/src` and `/usr/local/src`. The [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSRCSOURCECODE) says those directories should only be used for reference purposes.

For a build system I would use a temporary directory under `/tmp`, or the home directory of the (system) user which runs the builds, or a dedicated directory under `/srv` (*e.g.* `/srv/workspace` for Jenkins’ workspaces).

I wouldn’t use `/var/lib/foo`, that’s intended to store [`foo`’s variable state](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION), not its source code.

Comment: I kind of don't like either of those two locations

Comment: @amphibient `/srv` might be better, see my update. What don’t you like about `/tmp` or a home directory?

Comment: I don't like that those dirs have a general (usually human caused but also often caused by apps) tendency to collect a lot of trash, such as log files and miscellaneous other junk